# Dynamically detect if position:sticky is supported by the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-position, sticky

Is there a way to detect, using Javascript or jQuery, whether the browser supports `position:sticky` or not?

I know most modern browsers support it, but some older browsers and some mobile browsers don't.

I'm not interested in a polyfill. I want to take certain actions only if `position:sticky` works, otherwise just leave things as they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From modernizr:

```js
/*!
{
  "name": "CSS position: sticky",
  "property": "csspositionsticky",
  "tags": ["css"],
  "builderAliases": ["css_positionsticky"],
  "notes": [{
    "name": "Chrome bug report",
    "href":"https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322972"
  }],
  "warnings": ["using position:sticky on anything but top aligned elements is buggy in Chrome < 37 and iOS <=7+"]
}
!*/
define(['Modernizr', 'createElement', 'prefixes'], function(Modernizr, createElement, prefixes) {
  // Sticky positioning - constrains an element to be positioned inside the
  // intersection of its container box, and the viewport.
  Modernizr.addTest('csspositionsticky', function() {
    var prop = 'position:';
    var value = 'sticky';
    var el = createElement('a');
    var mStyle = el.style;

    mStyle.cssText = prop + prefixes.join(value + ';' + prop).slice(0, -prop.length);

    return mStyle.position.indexOf(value) !== -1;
  });
});
```

Source: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/positionsticky.js

with:

```js
prefixes = ' -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- '.split(' ');
```

Source: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/src/prefixes.js

Working example (w/o Modernizr dependencies):

```js
function browserSupportsPositionSticky() {
  var prop = 'position:';
  var value = 'sticky';
  var prefixes = ' -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- '.split(' ');

  var el = document.createElement('a');
  var mStyle = el.style;
  mStyle.cssText = prop + prefixes.join(value + ';' + prop).slice(0, - prop.length);
  
  return mStyle.position.indexOf(value) !== -1;
};

console.log(browserSupportsPositionSticky());
```

Comment: The solution is an interesting one! The principle is good, but it is not usable as it is... It is obviously a piece of Modernizr. To have it as a standalone JS function would be ideal.

Comment: Just extract the test case from the `.addTest()` call o.O

Comment: I tried. It's not clear where the prefixes object comes from.

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/src/prefixes.js

Comment: I just tested the "browserSupportsPositionSticky" on a version of iPad Safari where the inspector doesn't apply `position: sticky` (prefixed or not) and in dev tools calls it an invalid value for position and this function returned that it was supported. This was the only non-sticky-supporting browser I tested it on, so I doubt it's the only one that fails to detect lack of sticky support.

Answer (score 14):

A great and powerful way to check if a CSS feature is available is to use the `CSS.supports` JavaScript function:

```js
if (CSS && CSS.supports && CSS.supports("position", "sticky")) {
  // awesome: position:sticky is supported on this browser!
} else {
  // fallback: I cannot rely on position:sticky!
}
```

I hope this answers your question, but I think it's worth mentioning that if you're tempted to use `CSS.supports()` you should at least consider responding to a lack of feature just using CSS alone. While JavaScript is a great way to make dynamic changes to a page, you often don't need it to have your page respond to a lack of a feature. This is especially for CSS features like sticky.

E.g.

```css
/* 
  ...
  Basic styles for old browsers that don't support sticky go here.
  ... 
 */

@supports (position:sticky) { 
  /* Overrides to the above styles for modern "sticky" browsers go here */
}
```

And even then, you often don't even need to go this fancy. For example, let's say you have a nav bar that you would like to be `position:sticky` if possible, but otherwise just `position:absolute`. Even though some browsers don't understand `sticky`, you can say:

```css
.my-nav-bar {
  
  /* The fallback goes first */
  position: absolute; 

  /* This 'enhancement' is ignored if not understood, */
  /* but overrides the previous value if the browser supports it. */
  position: sticky; 

  top: 50px;
  /* ... etc ... */
}
```

Comment: What if CSS and CSS.supports are not supported, but position:sticky is?

Comment: <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
alert("ok");
if(CSS.supports("position:sticky"))
{
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
</html>

Comment: @clami219 Great question re: support! There seems to currently be ~95% support for `CSS.supports` and ~92% for `position:sticky`, according to caniuse.com. With the exception of Safari (incl iOS), introduction of _sticky_ trails that of _supports_ in all browsers, so I wouldn't generally hesitate to use this technique.

Comment: I've found that this works properly in cases where the accepted answer falsely reports support. I'd be in favor of this being the accepted answer.